# Mod Rewrite Sub Folder Structure to GET Variable

Tags: mod-rewrite, get

How would I write a url such as the following

```
www.linku.biz/profile/jacktrow
```

to

```
www.linku.biz/profile/?us=jacktrow
```

Being 'jacktrow' can be just letters (a-Z)

What would be the complete code I can place in a .htaccess in the directly of profile?

Much appreciated, mod rewrites and .htaccess are just such a pain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Then, put this code in your htaccess (in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-z]+)$ /profile/index.php?us=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have tried this code within the main root directly and the profile root directly. Error is displayed saying unknown path. It doesn't seem to recognize the code/file? I have saved it as .htaccess (without a file type)

Comment: What was the url you tried ? Also, did you enable `mod_rewrite` ?

Comment: www.linku.biz/profile/jacktrow which should be interpreted as www.linku.biz/profile/?us=jacktrow. Isn't mod_rewrite enabled through RewriteEngine on?

Comment: You have to edit your apache configuration. In `httpd.conf` you can add (or uncomment) following loadmodule directive: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Comment: Yes. Within httpd.conf it is already enabled (uncommented). Just to be clear do I place within the main root or the root of the profile directly? Either way it fails to recognize it. Is there anything I can try?

Comment: Within the main root, just like you did. In *profile* folder, is it `index.php` receiving `us` *GET* parameter ?

Comment: Yes within the profile directly its index.php with the GET parameter as 'us'. I can manually request profile/?us=jacktrow and it works. However when I request profile/jacktrow I get 'The requested URL was not found on this server'. I have the code above within a .htaccess file within the root directly. This is why .htaccess frustrates me.

Comment: Looks like your htaccess isn't interpreted. Are you sure it is named `.htaccess` ? This is a file with **no** name and `htaccess` extension. Are you on local or on a prod server ?

Comment: Yes it is only made with the extension .htaccess. I am using XAMPP on a local machine.

Comment: The access file is being interpreted. I tested by entering a string of rubbish into it then tried to access a page which caused a internal server error.

Comment: Could you try to replace my `RewriteRule` by this one and see if it redirects: `RewriteRule ^profile/([a-z]+)$ /profile/index.php?us=$1 [R=302,L]`

Comment: Ahhhhh. Finally I've figured it out. Thanks to that redirect. htdocs is considered my root directly within XAMPP however I have a folder above that called 'Linku5.0' which is considered my root but not to htaccess. It tries to rewrite it from straight from htdocs rather than Linku5.0/profile/jacktrow. Within .htaccess is there a way I can configure a base url so redirects are from Linku5.0/ then when I publish I can just remove this base URL rather then hard coding the directly Linku5.0 into all redirects.

Comment: Sure. You can add `RewriteBase /Linku5.0/` right after `RewriteEngine on` and the rule becomes `RewriteRule ^profile/([a-z]+)$ profile/index.php?us=$1 [L]`. But you can change that path in httpd.conf and make it pointing directly to your folder